# Array not defined in one JS file but not another

Tags: javascript

So in my scripts folder, I have `array.js`:

```
var array = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three'
]
```

`main.js`:

```
function arrayRandom(){
  var arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length));
```

and `sort.js`:

```
function alpha() {
  array.sort();
```

(I've stripped down a lot of the code for simplicity)

In my main.js the code runs fine. In sort.js I get the message "array is not defined" and I can't seem to figure out what's going on, as they are both set up the same. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Make sure `array.js` is loaded *before* `sort.js` in your html file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How are you including these files in HTML? It's easiest to tell what's amiss with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).